# the number of auxiliary verbs after "as" and "so"

Tags: usage, auxiliary-verbs, subject-auxiliary-inversion

I'm interested how many auxiliary verbs can stand after "*as*" and "*so*". By "*how many*" I mean one (e.g. "*would*") or two (e.g. "*would be*") or three (e.g. "*would have been*"). And by what rule should we choose this number?

As I understood from [here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/as-conjunction-inversion.3585429/):
**(1a)** *He got divorced, as his parents **had** years before*. — correct
**(1b)** *He got divorced, as his parents **had done** years before*. — correct
**(1c)** *He got divorced, as **had** his parents years before*. — correct
**(1d)** *He got divorced, as **had done** his parents years before*. — correct
Also I think:
**(1e)** *He got divorced and so **had** his parents years before*. — correct
**(1f)** *He got divorced and so **had done** his parents years before*. — correct

My example making up by analogy with #1a-f:
John:
**(2)** *I would eat something right now*.
Peter:
**(2a)** *As I **would***. — correct
**(2b)** *As I **would do***. — correct
**(2c)** *As **would** I*. — correct
**(2d)** *As **would do** I*. — correct
**(2e)** *So **would** I*. — correct
**(2f)** *So **would do** I*. — correct

If we add "*like to*", I think the correctness doesn't change:
John:
**(3)** *I would like to eat something right now*.
Peter:
**(3a)** *As I **would***. — correct
**(3b)** *As I **would do***. — correct
**(3c)** *As **would** I*. — correct
**(3d)** *As **would do** I*. — correct
**(3e)** *So **would** I*. — correct
**(3f)** *So **would do** I*. — correct

---

As I understood from [here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/inversion-in-a-comparative-clause-than-inversion.2813755/#post-14232513):
**(4a)** *Usually the cake would be excellent, as the coffee **would be***. — correct
**(4b)** *Usually the cake would be excellent, as **would be** the coffee*. — correct
**(4c)** *Usually the cake would be excellent, as the coffee **would***. — incorrect
**(4d)** *Usually the cake would be excellent, as **would** the coffee*. — incorrect
Also I think:
**(4e)** *Usually the cake would be excellent and so **would be** the coffee*. — correct
**(4f)** *Usually the cake would be excellent and so **would** the coffee*. — incorrect

My example making up by analogy with #4a-f:
John:
**(5)** *I would be glad to eat something right now*.
Peter:
**(5a)** *As I **would be***. — correct
**(5b)** *As **would be** I*. — correct
**(5c)** *As I **would***. — incorrect
**(5d)** *As **would** I*. — incorrect
**(5e)** *So **would be** I*. — correct
**(5f)** *So **would** I*. — incorrect

---

Do you agree?

Comment: There are many you are missing, and I am not sure this is a useful exercise. "He is getting a divorce as are his parents". "He has gotten a divorce as have his parents". He speaks good Russian as do his parents. They will arrive late as will he.  Also: I would eat something right now. So would I or "As would I" The others are wrong. Someone can go through the entire list but I will not. :)  [I'm interested **in** x]

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for the comment. To be better understood, I added two new sentences after the first sentence of my post. Here they are: "By "how many" I mean one (e.g. "would") or two (e.g. "would be") or three (e.g. "would have been"). And by what rule should we choose this number?"

Comment: Generally, never more than one **if using so or as**. "(5e) So would be I. — correct
(5f) So would I. — incorrect" are wrong. 5e is WRONG and 5f is RIGHT. :)

Comment: Also, your idea of analogy is not right.